# how do I sort socrata data?

Tags: api, socrata, soda

I am using CityOfchicago API's to learn few tech stacks., want to know is there any way I can make a call so that I get a sorted response?

something like 
https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/crimes.json?soryBy=date

Answer (score 0):

To sort, you'll need the `order` SoQL verb with the correct API endpoint. For the Chicago crime dataset, this will work:

```
data.cityofchicago.org/resource/6zsd-86xi.json?$order=Date
```

[Read more about SoQL](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries/) for other queries.